# ¿Como validar que una Variable o Dato de Celda no contenga caracter especial? (á|é|í|ó|ú|ñ|Ã)

Tags: phpexcel

Buenas estoy haciendo un programa en phpexcel que me realice una query para insertar en una db de nombres. Cuando valido los caracteres de la variable nombre me da el siguiente error. Ajunto codigo y error

Codigo

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$archivo = "clientes.xlsx"; //El archivo excel lo pongo dentro de la variable $archivo
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($archivo);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($archivo); //Cargo el archivo
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); //Me situo en la hoja 1
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); //Saco la cantidad de Filas para saber cuantos nombres tengo.
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
$contador=0; //Para saber cuantos nombres contienen caracteres especiales y no insertarlos en la db

echo "<br><tr> INSERT INTO [CM].[dbo].[xxx] ([NAME])
        <br>VALUES<br>";
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){
        echo "(".$sheet->getCell("A".$row)->getValue().")"."<br>";
            //*Ã¡±­¼º³‘Â,@#%&-+()/*"':;!?|~{}[]_  validar  si en name existe un caracter especial
            if (preg_match("/(á|é|í|ó|ú|ñ|Ã|'|¡|±|­|¼|º|³|‘|Â|,|@|#|%|&|+)/", $sheet->getCell("A".$row)->getValue()))
            {
            echo "Hay un caracter especial indebido,"."<br>";
            $contador=$contador++;
            }
                else {
                    echo "Todo esta bien"; 
                    }
}

echo "La cantidad de nombres que hay con error es:" .$contador;

echo "La cantidad de nombres es:".$highestRow;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Respuesta

```
INSERT INTO [CM].[dbo].[xxx] ([NAME])  VALUES (Guillermo)  Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 59 in C:\wamp\www\prueba\index1.php on line 23 Todo esta bien (Pedro) Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 59 in C:\wamp\www\prueba\index1.php on line 23 (MÃria) Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 59 in C:\wamp\www\prueba\index1.php on line 23
```

Comment: ME puedes aclarar, quieres limpiar el texto o quieres comprobarlo?

Comment: Quiero validarlo para que no tenga caracteres especiales los nombres.

Comment: for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){
   for ($i=0; $i<strlen($cliente['NAME'][$row]); $i++){ 
      if (strpos($nombres, substr($cliente['NAME'][$row],$i,1))===false){ 
        echo $cliente['NAME'][$row]." En la celda ".$sheet->getCell("B".$row)->getRow()."<br>";
        $contadorerror=$contadorerror+1;
         break;}